# Largest collection of subsets

Tags: combinatorics

I have been trying to solve a combinatorics problem and I reduced the problem to the following (which I cannot solve):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a collection of subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that for any $B_i,B_j\in\mathcal{B}$, we have $\lvert B_i\rvert=\log n$ and $\lvert B_i\bigcap B_j\rvert<2$. How large can you make $\mathcal{B}$? I am not looking for the best answer, I just need to show we can always find a $\mathcal{B}$ with $\lvert\mathcal{B}\rvert\sim n^\alpha$ for some constant $\alpha<1$.

Any ideas?

Comment: By $\log $, do you mean base $10 $ or base $ e $? I am guessing base $10 $, since one cannot have a cardinality as a decimal. So, the possible cardinalities of $ B_i $ are powers of $10$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you let $B_i$ be $[1+\log n(i-1),i\log n]$ you get $\frac n{\log n}$ disjoint sets, which gets larger than $n^\alpha$ for any given $\alpha \lt 1$